Omit and definition of K
Why in the TypeScript built-in utility type Omit, which is defined as:
type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

does K extend keyof any rather than keyof T?

@jonrsharpe TYVM for reformatting my question.

There's a lot of back and forth about that on the relevant Github issue, and about two dozen related issues.
In essence, the Omit type was based on similar utility types that where defined in various existing TypeScript helper libraries, some of which were strict, and some of which were permissive. The TypeScript team opted to go with the permissive variant.
As discussed in the issue, you can define your own OmitStrict type and configure ESLint to generate an error when the regular Omit type is used.
The type could look something like this (from here):
type OmitStrict<T, K extends keyof T> = T extends any
    ? Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
    : never;

And the ESLint rule (from here):
{
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/ban-types': [
      'error',
      {
        types: {
          Omit: "Prefer `OmitStrict`.",
        },
      },
    ],
  }
}


All the answers have been good so far, but this takes the completion prize IMO for providing background and offering a complete suggestion (with both code and rule config). I really appreciate that you formulated your answer in such a way that a complete novice could just grab the code and paste it on their project.

Without discussing whether the definition of "Omit" is good or what can be used as an alternative, here is what it does:
It creates a type from T that does not have the listed keys, irrespective of whether those keys existed on T to begin with. Think of it as a set-substraction, {1,2,4} - {1,3} is well defined to mean {2,4} in maths, and Omit works the same way. This example compiles:
interface Todo {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  completed: boolean;
  createdAt: number;
}

type TodoShort = Omit<Todo, "completed" | "description" | "nonexisting">

const todoShort : TodoShort = {
  title: "Clean room",
  createdAt: 1615544252770
}


If Omit were defined as Omit<T, K extends keyof T>, then we would not be allowed to define TodoShort with the "nonexisting"-omission and this code would not compile.

I'm new to SO and therefore am still not well acclimated to proper etiquette, but the code not compiling seems - in my limited understanding - to be desired.
Suppose that I refactor Todo so that the attribute description is shortened to desc - the type system will not "catch" this and I may end up with a hard to debug issue.
I am trying my absolute best to understand what would be the point of having the possibility of listing non-existing keys, but I am struggling. Other utility types, such as Pick do perform this validation, so I am thoroughly confused.
But TYVM!

@thewaver you can definitely make the point that a stricter definition of Omit would be more useful and many would agree, including myself actually. But as many things in computers, decisions have been made and this is how it works now, and I didn't want to dilude the explanation of this with opinions.

Appreciated once more.
